# To know the displacements of all the nodes pertaining to just a particular nodeset

Tags: python

I am working on python Scripting in ABAQUS.

I wanted to know the displacements of all the nodes pertaining to just a particular nodeset(PU-NODES-FATIGUE).

I try to access it by writing the following code but encountered an error saying:

> keyError : PU-NODES-FATIGUE

I tried to even change the name to different set so as to check the output but it is still the same error.

It would be very greatful if anyone can throw some light on this.

Thank you in advance.

#### The code is:

```
>>> print 'Node sets = ',odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets.keys()
    Node sets =  [' ALL NODES', 'BC-PU-SYM-Z', 'PU-NODES-FATIGUE', 'SET-8']
>>> fatigue = odb.rootAssembly.instances['PU-1'].nodeSets['PU-NODES-FATIGUE']
KeyError: PU-NODES-FATIGUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before requesting data you may want to check if such Sets are in the model.

Check the model instances first

```
print odb.rootAssembly.instances.keys()
```

If 'PU-1' exists, check the keys under it

```
print odb.rootAssembly.instances['PU-1'].keys()
```

If this last print returns 'PU-NODES-FATIGUE' I genuinely don't know what's wrong.

At last, this may work

```
fatigue = odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['PU-NODES-FATIGUE']
```

Comment: ..Thank you for your valuable information. I should not have included 'instances' after the 'rootassembly' in the last line of the code.